# Confused about Haskell Monad Transformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am confused about where `m` should be placed on the right side of the Monad transformers?

For example:

`WriterT` is defined as

```
newtype WriterT w m a = WriterT { runWriterT :: m (a, w) }
```

while `ReaderT` is defined as

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
```

but NOT

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: m (r -> a) }
```

Comment: Have you tried writing the monad instance for the `m (r -> a)` version?

Comment: Any operations that desires the reader monad information (type variable `r`) is unable to interleave monadic actions of type `m` and instead only able to return a value of type `a`.  So imagine I was a reader monad with `r ~ FilePath` (ReaderT IO FilePath).  The reader monad can obtain the path but can't actually read the file.

Answer (score 4):

The placement of the monad `m` will depend on the function and operation of the monad transformer that's being applied to the underlying monad `m`, so it's determined by what functionality the reader and writer are supposed to be adding to the monad.

It helps to remember that `runReaderT` and `runWriterT` aren't really *doing* anything, despite their suggestive names.  They're just unwrapping a newtype, and it's the things they wrap that are transforming the monad `m`.

What I mean by this is, given a monad `m`, you can add a reader to it by considering monadic actions of type:

```
r -> m a
```

and you can add a writer to it by considering monadic actions of type:

```
m (a, w)
```

and you can add a reader, writer, and state to it by considering monadic actions of type:

```
r -> s -> m (a, s, w)
```

(That is, you don't need any of the transformer wrappers to do this, though they can make it more convenient, particularly since you can use existing operators like `>>=` and `<*>` instead of having to define your own.)

So, when you add a reader to a monad `m`, why don't you instead place the `m` at the beginning and consider monadic actions of following type?

```
m (r -> a)
```

You could, in fact, do this, but you'd quickly discover that this method of adding a reader doesn't actually add very much functionality to the monad `m`.

For example, suppose you're writing a function that should look up a key in a table of values, and you want to carry the table in a reader.  Since the lookup can fail, you'd like to do this in the `Maybe` monad.  So, you'd like to write something like:

```
myLookup :: Key -> Maybe Value
myLookup key = ...
```

However, you want to enhance the `Maybe` monad with a reader that provides the table of keys and values.  If we do this using the `m (r -> a)` pattern, we get:

```
myLookup :: Key -> Maybe ([(Key,Value)] -> Value)
```

Now, let's try to implement it:

```
myLookup k = Just (\tbl -> ...)
```

Already, we see a problem.  We have to provide a `Just` (indicating that the lookup has succeeded) before we're allowed to write code to access the `\tbl`.  That is, the monadic action (failure or success with return value) cannot depend on information in the `r` which should have been obvious from the signature `m (r -> a)`.  Using the alternate `r -> m a` pattern is more powerful:

```
type M a = ([Key,Value]) -> Maybe a
myLookup :: Key -> M Value
myLookup key tbl = Prelude.lookup key tbl
```

@Thomas_M_DuBuisson gave another example.  If we're trying to read an input file, we might write:

```
readInput :: FilePath -> IO DataToProcess
readInput fp = withFile fp ReadMode $ \h -> ...
```

It would be nice to carry around configuration information like file paths in a reader, so let's transform it using the pattern `m (r -> a)` to:

```
data Config = Config { inputFile :: FilePath }
readConfig :: IO (Config -> DataToProcess)
readConfig = ...um...
```

and we're stuck because we can't write an IO action that depends on the configuration information.  If we'd used the alternate pattern `r -> m a`, we'd be set:

```
type M a = Config -> IO a
readConfig :: M DataToProcess
readConfig cfg = withFile (inputFile cfg) ReadMode $ ...
```

Another issue, raised by @cdk, is that this new "monadic" action type:

```
m (r -> a)
```

isn't even a monad.  It's weaker (just an applicative).

Note that adding a merely applicative reader to a monad could *still* be useful.  It just needs to be used in computations where the computational structure does not depend on the information in `r`. (So, if the underlying monad is `Maybe` to allow a computation to signal an error, the values from `r` can be used in the computation but the determination of whether or not the computation succeeds must be independent of `r`.)

However, the `r -> m a` version is strictly more powerful and can be used as both a monadic and applicative reader.

Note that some monadic transformations are useful in multiple forms.  For example, you can (but only sometimes, as @luqui pointed out in a comment) add a writer to an `m` monad in two ways:

```
m (a, w)  -- if m is a monad this is always a monad
(m a, w)  -- this is a monad for some, but not all, monads m
```

If `m` is `IO`, then `IO (a,w)` is way more useful than `(IO a, w)` -- with the latter, the written `w` (e.g., an error log) can't depend on the result of executing the `IO` action!  Also, again `(IO a, w)` isn't actually a monad; it's just an applicative.

On the other hand, if `m` is `Maybe`, then `(Maybe a, w)` writes something whether the computation succeeds or fails, while `Maybe (a, w)` loses all the log entries if it returns `Nothing`.  Both forms are monads and can be useful in different situations, and they correspond to stacking the transformers in different orders:

```
MaybeT (Writer w)  -- acts like  (Maybe a, w)
WriterT w Maybe    -- acts like  Maybe (a, w)
```

The same is **not** true for stacking `Maybe` and `Reader` in different orders.  Both of these are isomorphic to the "good" reader `r -> Maybe a`:

```
MaybeT (Reader r)
ReaderT r Maybe
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `(m a, w)` is not actually a valid monad transformer.

Comment: @luqui: Yup, you're right.  I tried to update the answer to address your comment.